# bottle pandas return xls file

Tags: python, pandas, bottle

Is it possible to define a route in bottle which would return a file?

1. I have a mongo database which is accessed by pandas.
2. Pandas generates a xls file based on a request parameters.

Two steps above are clear and easy to implement.
The third step is the one I have a problem with.

3. Define a bottle route which would return a file to download by user.

I don't want to use static previously generated files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Pandas but you need to get binary contents of a xls file to send to a user via a Bottle route. Modified example from [here](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html) for Python 3:

```
from io import BytesIO
from bottle import route, response
from pandas import ExcelWriter


@route('/get-xlsx')
def get_xlsx():
    output = BytesIO()
    writer = ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')
    # Do something with your Pandas data
    # ...
    pandas_dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    writer.save()
    response.contet_type = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    response.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="report.xlsx"')
    return output.getvalue()
```

When a user click a link that corresponds to this route, a file download dialog for "report.xlxs" will open in their browser.

Comment: BytesIO is an in- memory file-like object. I guess you can even return it directly without getvalue() because WSGI protocol accepts file-like iterable objects as payload.